# Stacked bar chart in Qlik Sense

Tags: stacked-chart, qliksense

In QlikSense I am trying to create a stacked bar chart. My dataset is looks like:

```
Country  Type   Amount
Brazil   Cars   10
Brazil   Bus    15
Brazil   Bike   10
Canada   Cars   5
Canada   Bus    15
Canada   Bike   10
Egypt    Cars   5
Egypt    Bus    20
Egypt    Bike   5
```

And I would like a graph that looks like the following. However, I can't even select a stacked bar chart if I only add one measure, which is the Amount field. I think I should group by Country, should I also group by Type? Or should I add each Type as measure, is that possible and how can I do that?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create it in QS

1. Add barchart object to your sheet
2. press `Add dimension` button and pick `Country` field
3. press `Add measure` button and pick `Amount` and then `Sum(Amount)`

   - at this point you will have chart that looks like this:

[image]

4. From the properties panel on the right under `Data` --> `Dimensions` press `Add` button and pick `Type` field

[image]

- now your chart looks like this:

[image]

5. from the properties panel again `Appearance` --> `Presentation` --> and pick `Stacked`

[image]

- and your chart will be stacked

[image]

Live chart [here](https://charts.qlikcloud.com/5ae19e42bfd98c00100cf173/chart.html)